# Excel uses to much memory

Tags: excel, vba

i use a makro in VBA Excel. Which imports 60 000 Line's of Data from
a Text File into 60 000 Line's and 5 Column's
Each time i use it , the memory of the Excel file uses more and more memory up to gigabyte's.
The makro only overwrites the the existing cells.

Makro :

```
Const PC As String = "\\pe-copystation\elektronik"
Const Bewegungsjournal_Daten As String = PC & "\MP100D\Elektro\inbox\BEWEGUNG.opj"

Sub Datenimport()

    Dim Temp As String
    Dim Artikel As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Zeile, Spalte As Integer
    Dim Datum As Date
    
    Dim Artikeldaten As Variant
    
    Const Tabelle As String = "Tabelle1"
     
    Sheets(Tabelle).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Zeile = 1  'Startzeile
    
    Open Bewegungsjournal_Daten For Input As #1
        
       Do
        
        Line Input #1, Temp$
        'Pos = InStr(Temp$, "$S")
        Artikeldaten = Split(Temp, "$")
        Zeile = Zeile + 1
        
  
            Artikel = Right(Artikeldaten(1), Len(Artikeldaten(1)) - 1)
            'MsgBox (Artikeldaten(1))
            Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 1) = Artikel
                Artikel = Right(Artikeldaten(2), Len(Artikeldaten(2)) - 1) 'Vorzeichen
                Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 2) = Artikel
                    Artikel = Right(Artikeldaten(3), Len(Artikeldaten(3)) - 1) 'Menge
                    Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 3) = Artikel
                        Artikel = (Right(Artikeldaten(7), Len(Artikeldaten(7)) - 3)) 'Datum
                        Artikel = Left(Artikel, 2) & "." & Mid(Artikel, 3, 2) & "." & Right(Artikel, 2)
                        Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 4) = CDate(Artikel)
                            Artikel = Right(Artikeldaten(8), Len(Artikeldaten(8)) - 3) 'Zeit
                            Artikel = Left(Artikel, 2) & ":" & Right(Artikel, 2)
                            Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 5) = Artikel
                                Artikel = Right(Artikeldaten(9), Len(Artikeldaten(9)) - 3) 'Benutzer
                                Sheets(Tabelle).Cells(Zeile, 6) = Artikel
        Loop Until EOF(1)
    Close #1
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic                           'Autoberechnung wieder anschalten
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider storing all the values in an array first then write into the worksheet once using the array. Read/Write cell is slow in general and you are doing it 6 times per loop =360k times.

Comment: Thanks for the replies , it work but have problems formatting the data.
I will work with the array solution it is really much faster.
However, the speed was never the problem but that Excel consumes so much memory, every time I start the macro almost doubles the memory consumption. With such a simple function.
I think this is a bug in Excel 2019 or VBA.

Comment: I don't think 60k lines is a lot to process and will consume so much memory, have you tried with a smaller sample and see the memory consumed drop?

Comment: I have tried it with about 4000 rows and 3 columns ,every time I start the macro the memory Excel needs increases. So I get  at 20-30 times to more than 1 GB according to Tastmanager.

Comment: The early part of your code will `ClearContents` the entire worksheet, what happens if you comment out those? i.e. Try with an empty worksheet and remove the code that `ClearContents`.

Comment: It does not change anything. If i use these Lines : Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(MaxZeile, 3)) = Daten -> it worked . These Lines :  For Zeile = 1 To MaxZeile
        For i = 0 To 2
            Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Zeile, i + 1) = Daten(Zeile, i)
        Next i
    Next Zeile

Comment: Excel Memory increase .It looks like "Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells..." causes the memory of Excel to increase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VBA expert, but importing data sounds like a job for PowerQuery to me. You can trigger data refreshes with PowerShell/VBA using the RefreshAll method.

Basically what I would do is set up a data load with the CSV file in question and if you don't want to manually trigger the refresh, then do it with VBA. PowerQuery refreshes the same table, so just like your script, this is going to overwrite all the cells.

Here is a quick link how to set up the data load (not my website): https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/import-data-csv-using-power-query-get-transform/

Comment: Thanks for the replies , both work but have problems formatting the data.
I will work with the array solution it is really much faster.
However, the speed was never the problem but that Excel consumes so much memory, every time I start the macro almost doubles the memory consumption. With such a simple function.
I think this is a bug in Excel 2019 or VBA.

Comment: Could you precise what is not working when formatting the data? The PowerQuery language is really good at transforming stuff, so maybe I can point you to the right direction. :)

Comment: If the Data of one Zell have not the same format while import , then Powerquery tells an Error. It's easyier for me to use VBA.

Comment: Could you import using Text and then apply your VBA code to change the content?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it is easier to use only VBA.